# Node import looking for main file of npm module in wrong place

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I have published an npm module: [react-bootstrap-tooltip-button](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-tooltip-button)

The `package.json` file states

```
"main": "lib/TooltipButton.js",
```

Installing the module as a dependency of another project using npm works fine, however, when I try to import it like so

```
import TooltipButton from 'react-bootstrap-tooltip-button'
```

I get an error revealing that node is looking for the main file in the wrong place:

```
Module not found: [CaseSensitivePathsPlugin]
`[...]/node_modules/react-bootstrap-tooltip-button/TooltipButton.js`
does not match the corresponding path on disk - File does not exist.
```

Why is `lib/` missing in the path?

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, the code was fine, but this is a bug in Webpack. Restarting the dev server solved the problem (just recompiling wasn't enough).

Found the hint here: [create-react-app issues on github](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/660)